# How do I denote a pure virtual function in a UML class diagram?

Tags: c++, uml, class-diagram, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

I am a student learning C++. I am creating a UML class diagram for my program that involves inheritance and abstract / concrete classes, but I'm not too sure how I would denote a pure virtual function. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The UML standard does indicate that a behavioral feature (e.g. a method/operation) can have its property `isAbstract` set to indicate that it is abstract and has no implementation.  There is however nothing about how this should be shown in the diagram.

According to [uml-diagrams.org](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/operation.html) and other sources,  in older UML versions (1.4.x), an abstract operation was shown with a name in *italic* or with a textual `{abstract}` marker following its name. The italic convention was widely used (See also [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190714162247/http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/35)).

The current UML doesn't use anymore use italic and does not indicate how to represent the `isAbstract` property.  Nevertheless, the `{abstract}` marker should still be valid.

Comment: P. 99 of UML 2.5: _The name of an abstract Classifier is shown in italics, where permitted by the font in use_

Comment: @ThomasKilian yes, but this applies only to classifiers not to operations.   It's very different from the 1.4 standard, where it is explicitly said "*If this class does not implement the operation; that is, does not supply a method, then the operation may be marked as “{abstract}” or the operation signature may be italicized to indicate that it is abstract.*" (page 3-46).

Comment: @ThomasKilian the notation of Behavioral Features and of Operations do not mention anymore italic notation (but still underlined for static).  But both use the { property... } notation (even if `abstract` is not explicitly mentioned p108-109 + 116).  I agree however with you in that I wouldn't be shocked by an italic, since  it was so heavily used in the past (including pre-UML notations, e.g. in GoF).

Comment: Since both Italic as {abstract} are only indicated in relation to Classifiers, you could maybe update your answer. It currently states that {abstract} should be valid, and there is no indication in the specs that says that it is more valid than italics.

Comment: I guess the comments above are good enough. Nothing is perfect, even specifications.

Comment: The second links seems dead.

Comment: @Ben_LCDB Thanks for letting me know! We were lucky: the wayback machine has saved a snapshot of the page in 2019. I’ve updated the link accordingly.